# Click font awesome button python & selenium

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, selenium

I am trying to run Python / Selenium script that clicks a font awesome button on a static HTML website.

I've tried several ID names but I keep getting exceptions.

When I right click and 'inspect element' the ID tag is what I have enetered currently.

I don't want to use xpath.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Python script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import unittest

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.baransjd.com")
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_id("i.fa.fa-linkedin-square.fa-2x")
click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.close()
```

HTML for the font awesome button (no CSS)

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/dan-b-33b89b158/"> <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x" style="color:#5B5B5B"></i></a>
```

Comment: `"i.fa.fa-linkedin-square.fa-2x"` is a CSS selector. So, using `find_element_by_id` won't work. Use `find_element_by_css_selector` instead. `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("i.fa.fa-linkedin-square.fa-2x").click()`.

Comment: Hi Keyur, this solved my problem.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

use css selector (There is no ID associated with the respective element). you can't use **id** here in your case to find your desired element.

```
driver.get("http://www.baransjd.com/")
linkdin= driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.container i[class*='linkedin-square']")
linkdin.click()
```

Comment: Did you try the code provided by me ? It worked at my end though. More over I have provided css selector as per your requirement which is more stable as compared to keyur css selector

Answer (score 0):

You may refer this,

Its class, Not ID.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//i[@class='fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x']").click()
```

Comment: Appreciate the response, but I am trying to avoid using x-path in this scenario.